# Set date field in newform to selected date on calendarview

Tags: 2010, calendar, date-time

I'm looking for a solution where I first select a date on the calendar-view, when I add a new item, the selected date should be filled in on a field in my newform.aspx.

Is this possible out of the box? (I guess not...) Or how would you fix this?
Javascript? Infopath? Custom development?

One thing I have in mind (but it's a lot of work) 
Create a custom ribbon action where you first select the date, then click on the ribbon button. With javascript you get the selected date, put it in the querystring. On newpage.aspx you get the querystring (if exists) and fill in the date on the field.

Comment: I am interested in know how you have resolved this Thanks in advane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are viewing a SharePoint 2010 Calendar, if you hover over a day, it will show the "Add" link.  Clicking that will default the date to the date you hovered over.